# Rings isomorphic to a proper subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Is there a theory for rings which are isomorphic to a proper subring? Which of the following rings have this property?

$$ \mathbb{R} , M_2(\mathbb{R}) , \mathbb{C} \; and \; M_2(\mathbb{Z})$$

Answer (score 3):

I know that $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to a proper subring of $\mathbb{C}$, assuming the axiom of choice.  I have no idea about $\mathbb{R}$ and $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.  I don't know about any study about such rings either.  But here is a proof that $\mathbb{C}$ has a proper subring isomorphic to itself.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a transcendental basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Then, note that $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}\cup\{x\}$ are equinumerous, where $x$ is a transcendental variable.  Therefore, a bijection $f:\mathcal{B}\cup\{x\}\to \mathcal{B}$ lifts to a field isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\big(\mathcal{B}\cup\{x\}\big)\to \mathbb{Q}(\mathcal{B})$, which then can be extended to an isomorphism $\Phi:\overline{\mathbb{Q}\big(\mathcal{B}\cup\{x\}\big)}\to \overline{\mathbb{Q}(\mathcal{B})}$.  That is, $\Phi:\overline{\mathbb{C}(x)}\to \mathbb{C}$ is an isomorphism of fields.  Now, consider the canonical injection $\iota:\mathbb{C}\to\overline{\mathbb{C}(x)}$.  Then, we see that the image $S$ of $\mathbb{C}$ under the composition $\Phi\circ \iota$ is a proper subring of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: And why do you think this wont work for $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because I don't know what kind of extensions I should take to get from $\mathbb{Q}(\mathcal{T})$ to $\mathbb{R}$, if $\mathcal{T}$ is a transcendental basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  For $\mathbb{C}$ it is easy, just take the algebraic closure.  Plus, since an algebraic closure is a splitting field, this allows us to extend $\varphi$ to $\Phi$.

Comment: Shouldn't it work if you exchange $\mathbb{Q}$ by its algebraic closure and for $\mathbb{R}$ you intersect it with $\mathbb{R}$? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question.  I will think about it.

Comment: @zvi thanks. How about $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Comment: @Zvi I just remembered that the only non-zero function from reals into reals that preserves addition and multiplication is the identity function. So the field of real numbers is not isomorphic to a proper subring. Am I right ?!

Comment: @alexalexeq  Great argument.  I suggest that you put that into your question, so that people see you have made a very good attempts.  You may be able to draw more attention that way.

Comment: Regarding $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and indeed $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, I do not expect that they have proper subrings isomorphic to themselves, but haven't yet found good arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should look at [A ring isomorphic to a proper subring of itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784573/a-ring-isomorphic-to-a-proper-subring-of-itself/1786441)
2. If you have enough background in the topics of algebra, then you should read https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321183071_Rings_isomorphic_to_their_nontrivial_subrings